# Design: Having references in the subclass of a field in the superclass

Tags: oop

First of all, I have no idea if the title even reflects my question. I apologize and kindly request to change it if you have a better idea.

Now, the problem I have is mainly a design problem. I am not sure if what I want is a good practice but it's d*mn convenient.

I have an Interface called **IMovement**.

Two classes implement **IMovement**: **VelocityMovement**, **SplineMovement**.

I also have a class called **Sprite**. A Sprite has an **IMovement**.

Finally, I have two sublcasses of Sprite: **Player** and **Enemy**.

I **KNOW** that **Player** will **ALWAYS** have **VelocityMovement** and
I **KNOW** that **Enemy** will **ALWAYS** have **SplineMovement**.

Is it wrong (either by design or practical) to have, aside from the superclasses reference to IMovement, an attribute to the VelocityMovement or SplineMovement from Player or Enemy respectively?

In other words:

```
Interface IMovement {
  public Vector2 getPosition(int time);
}

class VeloctiyMovement implements IMovement { 
   public Vector2 velocity;

   public Vector2 getPosition(int time) { ... }
}

class SplineMovement implements IMovement { 
   public Spline spline;

   public Vector2 getPosition(int time) { ... }
}

class Sprite {
  IMovement movement;
}

class Player extends Sprite {
  public VelocityMovement velocityMovement;

  public Player() {
    velocityMovement = new VelocityMovement();
    movement = velocityMovement;
  }
}

class Enemy extends Sprite {
  public SplineMovement splineMovement;

  public Enemy() {
    splineMovement = new SplineMovement();
    movement = splineMovement();
  }
}
```

The reason I want to have the reference in the subclass is convenience. Half the times I need the velocity field from Player, and half the other times I don't care. This happens in a game where the method gets called approximately 100 times per second.

The reason I am pointing out the 100 times is because I also am concerned if casting is expensive.

Example, instead of:

```
// When I need the velocity
Vector2 velocity = ((VelocityMovement)player.movement).velocity;
...

// When I don't care
Vector2 position = player.movement.GetPosition(time);
...
```

I can now do this:

```
Vector2 velocity = player.VelocityMovement.velocity;
...

Vector2 position = player.movement.GetPosition(time);
...
```

So my question is: Should Player have a VelocityMovement field and an Enemy have a SplineMovement? Or is this a bad design?

I would like your thoughts.

***UPDATE***

I now remembered why I chose to have a field IMovement instead of having Sprite implement IMovement (as [JacobM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645710/design-having-references-in-the-subclass-of-a-field-in-the-superclass/1645842#1645842) correctly suggests).

It is because in some cases, Enemy could have SplineMovement and in others VelocityMovement.

Although I, incorrectly, said "I KNOW that Enemy will ALWAYS have SplineMovement", I should have stated that, I know an Enemy has VelocityMovement in places where I gather all enemies with VelocityMovements. I hope you understand me (otherwise I feel like an idiot).

For example:

```
List<Enemy> enemies = GetAllVelocityMovementEnemies();
```

I do this because somewhere in my game logic, I want to affect only the group of enemies that have VelocityMovements.

So, although JacobM's answer is perfectly valid as a design, this is not for my case. Otherwise I would have to subclass Enemy with EnemyVelocityMovement and EnemySplineMovement and so on and so forth.

So, sorry for the misunderstanding, I have decided that [Brian Agnew's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645710/design-having-references-in-the-subclass-of-a-field-in-the-superclass/1645756#1645756) answer is the best one for my design.

Oh, and yes, waring about casting is indeed premature optimization. ;)

Comment: It might help if you tagged this according to the language.

Comment: Although I mostly care about the design, if it helps it's C# (but could be Java as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about optimisation for the moment. Premature optimisation will cause you grief that is quite likely not warranted.

So, to answer your question, don't duplicate fields across the hierarchy - it's a maintenance headache and your perceived time-saving will be negligible. If you follow the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) then you'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

Ask your classes to move (say) via something like:

```
player.move()
```

otherwise (as you're discovering), you have to find their `IMovement`, and then cast it, and then ask that for the velocity, and that really breaks encapsulation. Your Player/Enemy classes will likely have different `move()` implementations, depending on their particulars.

You may not want a `move()` method, but what I'm trying to demonstrate is that the intelligence is contained *in the class*, not in the calling code. So you shouldn't have to expose your `IMovement` objects at all.

Finally, I would only optimise after getting it working, *and* measuring it to determine that you have a problem!

Comment: I updated the my question. Player/Enemy do have a base class: Sprite. Which indeed contains an IMovement.

My question is ultimately, if Player/Enemy should ALSO have a VelocityMovement/SplineMovement apart from the IMovement they inherit from Sprite.

Comment: Note: The VelocityMovement/SplineMovement have the SAME reference with their IMovement reference in the base class Sprite

Comment: Also, getVelocity applies only in the VelocityMovement, not in the IMovement (since SplineMovement doesn't have velocity). So getVelocity() cannot be in sprite, but rather in Player.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to try to write code, but perhaps, if the language you are using supports generic types, you could do something like

```
class Sprite<T extends IMovement> {
   T movement;
}

class Player extends Sprite<VelocityMovement> {
}

class Enemy extends Sprite<SplineMovement>{
}
```

This way, when you ask for the player's movement object, you know already that it's a VelocityMovement (but of course you can also refer to it as an IMovement).

Comment: Awesome idea! Never thought of that! :P

Comment: I still think the real issue is encapsulation and that the objects should look after their movements themselves

Comment: I totally agree with the encapsulation issue. So I would have Sprite extends IMovement and VelocityMovement will have setVelocity.

Thank you both. ;)

Comment: I agree about encapsulation too, and I voted you up, Brian.  But I think generics adds value here also, so it was worth throwing into the mix.